# Is a grounding rod a good idea for a 60' tower attached to my house and mounted 3' deep?

Tags: grounding

I'm having a tower installed as my house is in a rural, treed area. On the tower will be a Starlink satellite (which needs a clear view of the sky) and a cell phone booster. The tower will be mounted 3 feet deep.

Is there any purpose to attaching it to a ground rod, or does the fact that it's already in the ground provide adequate protection against lightning?

Comment: I'm no civil engineer, but a three foot foundation on a sixty foot structure? That sounds a bit optimistic...

Comment: Probably you should ask this question on the DIY stack exchange. Check the help desk first. https://diy.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: I agree that cell and TV will benefit from a 60' tower.  But why the satellite antenna?  Do you understand how satellite works and what "clear view of the sky" means? Is the sat antenna OK with swaying back and forth in the wind, because older satellite tech does not like that one bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conductivity of your protective oxide (of your presumably steel tower, not wood) will not suffice for grounding and a copper grounding rod must used.

Ref: https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/protective-grounding-requirements-transmission-distribution-lines